# How to programatically hard code the date of build into an assembly

Tags: msbuild

I want to hard-code the date of build into my assembly.

I can easily do that manually but is there some way it can be achieved by the build process?

Comment: I found the following which works well for me [link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html)

Answer (score 1):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/tfsbuild/thread/7fdeabcc-2ef1-4c4f-9798-b69ebee0c3a3

Once you are able to get the timestamp, you can place it in your  property like so:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ClCompile>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>BUILD_TIME=$(Timestamp);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael however I had no idea (a) how to get the timestamp nor (b) what your suggested code is all about. Nevertheless, a fair bit of googling has sadly helped to confuse me even more.

Comment: Well, the code I provided can be placed in a msbuild project or property sheet.  I guess I should not have assumed that you are doing C++ (looking back, your use of the term 'assembly' should have been a big hint), as that code will only work for those types of projects. Perhaps you can clarify what exactly you are wanting to do with the timestamp?